# Avro default value for user defined types

Tags: avro

Is it possible to have a default value for a user defined type?

ie given the avdl:

```
protocol {
    record A { }

    record B {
       union { A, string } foo = A;
    }
}
```

record B is valid and `thing` by default is an instance of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, **`{}`**

idl:

```
protocol {
    record A { }

    record B {
       union { A, string } foo = {};
    }
}
```

results in the avsc:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "B",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "foo",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "A",
      "fields" : [ ]
    }, "string" ],
    "default" : { }
  } ]
}
```

This implies: `new` of the first type of the union, in this case A.